# Java substitute for function pointers

Tags: java, lambda

I'm looking to create a Sigma method. Coming from C I could use a function pointer, but I'm not certain of a similar construct of C. It seems that I could use Lambdas, though I'm unfamiliar of how they work outside of Scheme. If anyone could help me modify the code below it would be greatly appreciated.

```
public static int Sigma( int n , function f(int)) {
     int sum = 0;
     for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
          sum = sum + f(i);
     return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use functional classes/interfaces from the `java.util.function` package in Java 8+. Like IntUnaryOperator.

```
public static int Sigma(int n, IntUnaryOperator f){
     int sum = 0;
     for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
          sum = sum + f(i);
     return sum;
}
```

An even shorter version would use IntStream (same package)

```
public static int Sigma(int n, IntUnaryOperator f){
     return IntStream.range(0, n).map(f).sum();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming I understand your intent, you could pass a `Function<Integer, Integer>` and then perform a `range`, `map` and `sum` like

```
public static int Sigma(int n, Function<Integer, Integer> f) {
    return IntStream.range(0, n).map(f::apply).sum();
}
```

Comment: I apologize if this code is rudimentary, but could you explain what's going on here?

Comment: Might be better with `IntUnaryOperator`.